# Server Error (500) when trying to log in in Django admin page

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am having a little project and am trying to set up a website using Django, Apache 2 and mod_wsgi. Everything runs fine in the Django development server, and I can also open the front page of my site using apache.

However, when I try to log in into the admin page, or use my own custom log in page, I get a Server error (500). Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = ...

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "192.168.0.121", "127.0.0.1"]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/account'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='/login'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kraken.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kraken.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html        
    Alias /static /home/pi/kraken/static
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/pi/kraken/static/favicon.ico
    <Directory /home/pi/kraken/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/pi/kraken/kraken>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess kraken python-path=/home/pi/kraken python-home=/home/pi/.conda/envs/django
    WSGIProcessGroup kraken
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/kraken/kraken/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

I used chown :www-data on my database and my project folder

Comment: You need to look in the Apache error log for the reason for the error. If nothing shows, then temporarily set ``DEBUG=True`` in Django settings file and restart web server. If error is from Django, will then show the error in the browser.

Comment: Thank you Graham, I found what was wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 14):

I followed Graham Dumpleton's advice and found that the permissions on my database weren't sufficient. I fixed that using `chown www-data db.sqlite3`, and my problem was solved.

Comment: Hi Fork2, could you explain in a little more detail exactly how you went about changing permissions, or point me in that direction? I seem to be hitting the exact same problem and pretty sure it's a permissions issue...

Comment: Note that you may also need to change the permissions/owner of the enclosing folder of the `db.sqlite3` file.

Answer (score 6):

This happened with me due to `DEBUG = False`

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/error-reporting/

Django Documentation cleared the Issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run your web app on a live server then you must update this field in the **settings.py** file.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "192.168.0.121", "127.0.0.1"]
```

This must include the IP address of your web server, otherwise Django will raise a 500 server error like the one you are encountering.

Comment: I just contact the server at 192.168.0.121. The home page loads, so that should be ok

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, my url file had a {} brackets chagned it to [] under urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And it resolved it